# Logging the training in fastai

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to fit a ULMFiT model from fastai with `fit_one_cycle` method. On each step it prints into my jupyter notebook the current state (as in the picture). As I work from a remote server, it may sometimes disconnect and so far I need to log this intermediate state of my model.

I see two solutions here:

1) Set the logging in the fastai code, but I did not manage to find where the table is printed (the training is done via `fit` function, but it does not seem to have it written apparently).

2) Configure the jupyter notebook so that everything it prints, it duplicates into a logging file.

I have spent more than a day trying to implement any of the written solutions but did not succeed in it. If anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

Picture here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSVLogger callback](https://docs.fast.ai/callbacks.csv_logger.html#CSVLogger) while creating the learner object, it will write training logs into "history.csv" (default filename)